# Unable to query mysql database using jdbc preparedstatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to run the below jdbc code to get the object key:

```
String sqlSelectObjKey = "select OBJ_KEY from obj where OBJ_NM=? and OBJ_TYP_CD='CONN';";


    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {           
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(stmtSelectObjKey);
        statement.setString(1, "Postal Connector");

        rs = statement.executeQuery(stmtSelectObjKey);
        while(rs.next()) {
            this.executionLog.setObjKey(rs.getInt("OBJ_KEY"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }
```

But every time it results in below exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and OBJ_TYP_CD='CONN'' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
    at appMetadata.ConnectorMetadataLoad.insertExecutionLog(ConnectorMetadataLoad.java:67)
    at appCore.PostalCodeInterface.getPostalData(PostalCodeInterface.java:37)
    at appMain.PostalDataConnector.getPostalData(PostalDataConnector.java:19)
    at PostalDemo.main(PostalDemo.java:14)
```

Removing the place holder and setting the value directly works fine.

I am not sure where the syntax is wrong, I will appreciate if anyone can point out the error.

Comment: Are you sure that `?` is the correct placholder?

Comment: Yes, removing placeholder and setting value directly in the where clause also works.

Comment: The error tells us that the `?` is problematic. It looks like the `?` is not replaced by the string argument.

Comment: I debugged statement, it seems that it is replacing the placeholder but even then it results in the same error.

Comment: You should perhaps use `executeQuery()` with no args. As a side note, you should also use a placeholder for the second 'CONN'.

Comment: Oops, Thanks a lot Gyro Gearless. Removing argument from executeQuery works. Please give it as an answer to allow me to mark it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got Your error, why you are assigning the query again to the preparedstatment.

Your Code:

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement(stmtSelectObjKey);
statement.setString(1, "Postal Connector");
rs = statement.executeQuery(stmtSelectObjKey);
```

Code Should be:

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement(stmtSelectObjKey);
statement.setString(1, "Postal Connector");
rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Thats why you are getting syntax error for the ?. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

remove the `;` in your sql string and try it again.

the `;` is used in the most db-tools to seperate sql-strings but it is no standard sql.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
statement.executeQuery(stmtSelectObjKey);
```

use

```
statement.executeQuery();
```

it will work !!

Answer (score 0):

As you using `prepareStatement` the execute syntax is like below `prepareStatement.executeQuery()` So change your code like below

```
String sqlSelectObjKey = "select OBJ_KEY from obj where OBJ_NM=? and OBJ_TYP_CD='CONN';";


    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {           
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(stmtSelectObjKey);
        statement.setString(1, "Postal Connector");

        rs = statement.executeQuery();//Change is here
        while(rs.next()) {
            this.executionLog.setObjKey(rs.getInt("OBJ_KEY"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }
```

For more information [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score -1):

Replace below query

```
String sqlSelectObjKey = "select OBJ_KEY from obj where OBJ_NM=? and OBJ_TYP_CD='CONN';";
```

with

```
String sqlSelectObjKey = "select OBJ_KEY from obj where OBJ_NM=? and OBJ_TYP_CD='CONN'";
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Stefan Beike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28582362/1885518)